# Can't get my for loop to produce desired result

Tags: python, for-loop

Also tried an enumerate and a list comprehension. But I'll just focus on one thing and comment out the other methods I tried. I think maybe I was supposed to do something involving dictionaries?? But I have no idea how to do that. It wouldn't even let me define an empty dictionary. So the strategy I decided on is trying to write a program where if the user chooses a name, and that name is found in the list, the item in the index one to the right (which should be the appropriate phone number) will be returned. My for loop for this is towards the bottom.

> A contact list is a place where you can store a specific contact with
> other associated information such as a phone number, email address,
> birthday, etc. Write a program that first takes in word pairs that
> consist of a name and a phone number (both strings). That list is
> followed by a name, and your program should output the phone number
> associated with that name.

Ex: If the input is:

```
Joe 123-5432 Linda 983-4123 Frank 867-5309
Frank
```

the output is:

> 867-5309

```
 ''' Type your code here. '''
    
    userEntered = input()
    selectedName = input()
    
    
    makeDict = {}
    
    
    
    listLength = len(userEntered.split())
    
    #for key, value in enumerate(makeDict):
        #key = userEntered.split()[0:listLength:2]
        #value =  userEntered.split()[1:listLength:2]
        
        
    #findNumber = [str(x) for x in userEntered.split() if str(x) == selectedName]
    
    #for index, value in enumerate(userEntered.split()):
        #if selectedName == value:
            #print(value[index+1])
        
    
  i = 0
for x in userEntered.split():
    while i <= listLength:
        if x == selectedName:
            answer = x[i+1]
            print(answer)
            break
        i+=1
```

Enter program input (optional)

```
Joe 123-5432 Linda 983-4123 Frank 867-5309
Linda
```

Program output displayed here

> (Your program produced no output)

EDIT: Solution now working with:

```
i = 0
for x in userEntered.split():
    if userEntered.split()[i] == selectedName:
        answer = userEntered.split()[i+1]
        print(answer)
        break
    i+=1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let me explain you what is not working in your program.

One problem is you inner `while` loop. You use `i` there but you don't use `i` in condition, so it will always stop at first iteration or at last one. Even if it would work, you don't reset your `i` between loops, so it stays the same after `while`, which probably is not what you ment. If you remove `while` loop completely it should work!

Comment: Thanks! It's working after I changed it to:                                                                            
 i = 0
for x in userEntered.split():
    if userEntered.split()[i] == selectedName:
        answer = userEntered.split()[i+1]
        print(answer)
        break
    i+=1

Answer (score 1):

You can use `str.split()` to split the users/numbers and then `zip()` to create the dictionary. For example:

```py
userEntered = input().split()
selectedName = input()

dct = dict(zip(userEntered[::2], userEntered[1::2]))
print(dct[selectedName])
```

Prints (for example):

```
Joe 123-5432 Linda 983-4123 Frank 867-5309
Linda
983-4123
```

Comment: thank you. I see this works but I'll avoid this method for now as I'm a super noob and haven't learned zip in my course material yet.

Answer (score 1):

Another method would be using regex with groups to look for a name and number pattern, you may also create a dictionary from the found results. Let's say you get the input as you have mentioned before:

```
userEntered = input()
selectedName = input()
```

which *userEntered* is as below:

```
Joe 123-5432 Linda 983-4123 Frank 867-5309
```

then you may call findall from re as:

```
import re

contacts = dict(re.findall(r"([a-zA-Z]+)\s(\d+-\d+)", userEntered))
contacts[selectedName]
```

which prints the contact for *selectedName*, so if the *selectedName* was "Linda", it prints:

```
983-4123
```